# Why the output of binary logistic regression for coefficients in 2 analysis for the same set of data are the same but opposite?

Tags: regression, logistic, interpretation, binary-data, regression-coefficients

I have a set of data and I used binary logistic regression for finding the significant parameters as well as the coefficient of the parameters. I did the analysis for two stages. 
First, At the first stage around half of the dependent variables were 1 and the rest of them were 0.
Second, For the other stage, the rest of the dependent variables were 1 and the variables that in the previous stage we 1 now they get 0.
The output of this analysis is the same significant parameters for both stages and the coefficients are also the same values but opposite, it means one of them is negative and the other one is positive. 
What is the reason or explanation for this happening? did I follow the wrong direction for my regression analysis?
I used SPSS and R-Studio to do the analysis and both of them had similar results.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, by swapping the labels 1 and 0 of the Stage 1 dependent variable during Stage 2, you fitted the following binary logistic regression models:

Stage 1: log(p/(1-p)) = linear function of your predictors

Stage 2: log((1-p)/p) = linear function of your predictors

where p denotes the probability that your dependent variable in Stage 1 takes the value 1 and 1-p denotes the probability that it takes the value 1.

Since you can show algebraically that log((1-p)/p) = - log(p/(1-p)), the coefficients in the two models will be identical in absolute value but have opposite signs.

Not clear why you would want to proceed with Stage 2 - Stage 1 already provides all the information that you need.